# ggplot colour bar label date formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, date-formatting

Is it possible to format the number labels on a guide_colourbar to a date format e.g. `%b %Y`? So instead of having `17400  17700  18000  18300` on the `Closing Date` legend, there would be the `%b %Y` equivalents.

**Example plot**

[image: Example ggplot with guide_colourbar to format]

**Code used to produce the plot**

```
Area = c(1705, 902, 1496, 1257, 763)
ClosePrice = c(2292500, 977520, 1990680, 1720840, 855330)
HasTerrace = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
CloseDate = as.Date(c('2017-03-17', '2017-02-28', '2018-05-09', '2020-03-01',
                      '2017-01-09'))
data <- data.frame(Area, ClosePrice, HasTerrace, CloseDate)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Area, y=ClosePrice, shape=HasTerrace)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=CloseDate), size=3, alpha=0.8) +
  scale_color_viridis() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(expression(Indoor~Area~(ft^2)),
                     labels=label_comma()) +
  scale_y_continuous('Closing Price ($m)',
                     labels=label_number(accuracy=0.01, scale=10^-6)) +
  theme(legend.position='bottom', legend.box='vertical') +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title='Has a Terrace'),
         colour = guide_colourbar(title='Closing Date',
                                  barwidth=10,
                                  labels=label_date(format='%b %Y')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. The `guide_colorbar()` function does not accept the `labels` argument, so it ignores it. You need to add your labels to `scale_color_viridis`. However, that will create an error unless you also include `trans = "date"`.

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Area, y=ClosePrice, shape=HasTerrace)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour=CloseDate), size=3, alpha=0.8) +
  scale_color_viridis(name='Closing Date', 
                      trans = "date", 
                      labels = label_date(format = "%b %Y") )+
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(expression(Indoor~Area~(ft^2)),
                     labels=label_comma()) +
  scale_y_continuous('Closing Price ($m)',
                     labels=label_number(accuracy=0.01, scale=10^-6)) +
  theme(legend.position='bottom', legend.box='vertical') +
  guides(shape = guide_legend(title='Has a Terrace'),
         colour = guide_colourbar(barwidth=10))
```

[image]